# htaccess mod_rewrite: Simplifying URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been having trouble with the following rewrite. I'm certain mod_rewrite is enabled but not sure where I am going wrong.

I'm try to change the following pattern:

```
/profile/?userid=157&username=FirstL
```

to:

```
/profile/FirstL
```

I've tried many different rules, but the two I felt were the closest to being correct aren't working at all. My current failures below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /profile/+\?userid=$([^&\ ]+)&username=$([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /profile/?userid=$1&username=$2 [L,QSA]
```

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /profile/?userid=$1&username=$2 [L]
```

Full htaccess:

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /profile/+\?userid=$([^&\ ]+)&username=$([^&\ ]+)
    RewriteRule ^ /profile/%1/%2? [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /profile/?userid=$1&username=$2 [L,QSA]

    RewriteBase /

    DirectorySlash Off

    RewriteRule ^admin$ /admin/index.php [L,E=LOOP:1]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_LOOP} !1
    RewriteRule ^admin/index.php$ /admin [R=301,L]

    # remove .php
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
    RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]

    # remove index
    RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=301]

    # remove slash if not directory
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
    RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]

    # add .php to access file, but don't redirect
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
    RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

    #Force non-www:
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're losing the userID part of the URL, so when you try to internally rewrite that back, there's nothing there:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /profile/?userid=$1&username=$2 [L,QSA]
```

This rule says the first match is the "userid" and the second match is the "username", and you only have one match, and on top of that, it doesn't even begin with "profile".

You'll need to include the userid somewhere in the URL, otherwise there's no way to extract it.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /profile/+\?userid=([^&\ ]+)&username=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /profile/%1/%2? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /profile/?userid=$1&username=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks perfect. I threw it in but still no dice. I tried on another server just to make sure there wasn't something funky going on. I have another rewrite working so I'm not sure what's up

Comment: @Jamie this is in an htaccess file that is in your document root? Or in the profile folder?

Comment: It's on root. I have a few other rewrites working properly: removing extensions, index

Comment: @Jamie depending on your other rules, you may need to re-arrange the order (order matters).

Comment: I placed it at the top and also tried removing the other rules. No dice. I've edited my original to include my full htaccess just in case there is something I am missing. I also tried simplifying it by removing username with only userid remaining but same result.

Comment: @Jamie just realized, those `$` symbols don't belong in the first rewrite condition

Comment: Ahh, thanks @Jon Lin! That did the trick. Appreciate your help!